# NOLOCK at query level

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nolock, read-uncommitted

I've a query to run a SQL server table, in which, I am not concerned with the exact count. So, I want to specify NOLOCK for that query. But, query itself consists of multiple subqueries and multiple joins; so, it's quite dirty to put NOLOCK all around.

Although, I can set the transaction level "READ-UNCOMMITTED" for the tables, but that would change it for all other queries as well. I want to change the transaction level for that particular query, but without specifying NOLOCK in the query at multiple places. Is that possible?

Comment: "but that would change it for all other queries as well" - transaction isolation level is defined at the session level, it doesn't affect other sessions - and you can change your isolation level before and after this particular query. So I'm not clear on what "other queries" you're concerned about this affecting.

Comment: So, if I change before executing this statement. Will it not affect the other queries that are running on the same tables? Will they continue to run with the previous transaction level?

Comment: Yes, as I said, this is defined at the session level. Other sessions will use whatever isolation levels *they* have selected.

Comment: So, what would it take to make the transaction level change at a global level for a particular table?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be set globally for a particular table.